# SQL BETWEEN QUERY

Tags: mysql

Folks,

need help, i have this query to return all the data from the teamA between the last 12 mnonths. but i cant show the data correctly.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE team= 'teamA' BETWEEN ('2015-12-31') AND (DATE_SUB('2015-12-01',INTERVAL 12 MONTH)) 
ORDER BY date ASC;
```

can you help me?

PD: my english is very bad ;(

Comment: You need `WHERE team = 'teamA' AND <YourDateCol> BETWEEN <date1> AND <date2>`. Find a SQL tutorial.

Comment: Also, `DATE_SUB()` subtracts an Interval from a date. You'll need to put the earlier date first in your `BETWEEN` logic, like: `<yourdatefield> BETWEEN DATE_SUB('2015-12-01',INTERVAL 12 MONTH) AND '2015-12-31'`. Lastly, if your dates are string literals like that, you may want to cast them to date: `CAST('2015-12-01' AS DATE)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE team= 'teamA' AND time BETWEEN ('2015-12-31') AND (DATE_SUB('2015-12-01',INTERVAL 12 MONTH)) 
ORDER BY date ASC;
```

where time is date column